# Problems with vertical alignment of the blocks in a row with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I make web application using Bootstrap 3 and Ruby On Rails. On the index page I show all materials in blocks "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6" (on picture) and if the height of the blocks is different, then they are not aligned vertically

[image]

How do I align the blocks in a row, as in the picture 2???

[image]

I do not want to use a js or set common height for blocks

**UPDATE**

In index.html.haml:

```
.row
  - @parks.each do |park|
    .col-lg-4.hidden-md.hidden-sm.hidden-xs
      .map_index
        .image_wrapper
          = image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x200&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{park.latitude}%2C#{park.longitude}", class: "map_image"
        %h2
          = link_to park.address, park
```

**CSS** - bootstrap's default grid styles

Comment: where is your html and css. How could one possibly help you with no code

Comment: I added haml code, boostrap's style is default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use bootstraps `<div class="clearfix"></div>`

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/343/

the `clearfix` div is a responsive column reset

Answer (score 0):

So, I useв `.clearfix` after each three blocks which I outpuе with `each_slice()` Ruby-method. My **ruby-haml** code:

```
%h1.title Listing of Krasnodar's parks
.row
  - @parks.each_slice(3) do |park|
    - park.each do |p|
      .col-lg-4.col-md-4.hidden-sm.hidden-xs
        .map_index
          .image_wrapper
            = image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x200&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{p.latitude}%2C#{p.longitude}", class: "map_image"
          %h2
            = link_to p.address, p
    .clearfix

  - @parks.each_slice(2) do |park|
    - park.each do |p|
      .col-sm-6.hidden-lg.hidden-md.hidden-xs
        .map_index
          .image_wrapper
            = image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x200&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{p.latitude}%2C#{p.longitude}", class: "map_image"
          %h2
            = link_to p.address, p

  - @parks.each do |park|
    .col-xs-10.hidden-lg.hidden-md.hidden-sm.col-xs-offset-1
      .map_index
        .image_wrapper
          = image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x200&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{park.latitude}%2C#{park.longitude}", class: "map_image"
        %h2
          = link_to park.address, park
```